# Caching/storing Google API data in Android

Tags: android, caching, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-classroom

I'm using a Google API (in this case, Classroom) for an Android app using `com.google.api.services.classroom.Classroom`. I want to cache the results on the device for speed/offline usage. Is there a quick-and-easy way to do this that uses the same java API? Can put something like an HttpResponseCache in the middle there somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your definition of "quick-and-easy", but I think the accurate answer here is no (!)--those methods are designed to be used "online."